# Save image and edit text into a gallery

Tags: android, text, save, gallery, android-studio-2.2

i am trying to create an application which add text on a image like image editor and save it to the gallery. In this my image is coming from gallery or camera and text is added by user but problem is that the text on the image does not store in to the gallery

Could anyone offer any solutions here?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Post code you have done till now , general idea would be to create a `View` using `LinearLayout` add `textView` inside it on runtime , Create `Bitmap` of this `View` and save it to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: I'm nothing too do right. I'm just taking idea how it done. I'm beginner in this field
Thanks for your reply ....:) :)
but would you explain briefly ?? @Vikrant

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

1) Create a Linearlayout

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_you_need);
```

2) Add TextView

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    //tv.setText("Whatever you like");
    layout.addView(tv); // add TextView on runtime

    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    layout.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap saveBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());

    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    SaveImage(savebm);
```

3) Save the Bitmap

```
    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also please understand the need of `your_layout_view.invalidate()` , you may need this in future.